# Which is correct - have left or left?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense, past-simple

Which of these sentences is right:

- The cops usually arrive 20 minutes after the robbers have left.

OR

- The cops usually arrive 20 minutes after the robbers left.

Which is correct, **have left** or **left**? Or do I need a present tense?
And is 'arrive' being used properly here or do I need to change it to 'arrived'?

Comment: It sounds natural to me to use the present tense for both: "The cops usually arrive 20 minutes after the robbers leave." It is describing a continuing state of affairs.

Comment: No argument. But nobody would mind if you used the present perfect. The past tense doesn't fit.